# Travelling for work and refused access

Tags: germany, working-visas

I need some help urgently.

I am from Mauritius and I have a permanent job confirmed in Dusseldorf, Germany. I have contract and confirmation letter from the company and some other documents from it.

I came to London for 1 week and, today, I travelled to Dusseldorf but I was refused access because I do not have a work permit.

I was deported back to London and I was allowed to enter the country.

I was supposed to have my appointment at the German foreign office this Friday.

Normally, I do not need a visa to enter Germany if my purpose is for tourism. If I entered as a tourist, I would be able to go to the foreign office and do all the paperwork for the work visa, as I understood it. I didn't know this.

Now, as I was refused access, there is a stamp on my passport that looks like this (a cross on the stamp).

[image]

Has anyone ever encountered this? Can I make application for my visa from London or should I go back to my home country?

Will I still be able to enter Germany with this stamp on my passport? I really don't know what to do.

Comment: > I have contract and confirmation letter from the company and some other documents from it. -- but not a work visa? What was the company thinking? This throws up so many red flags.

Comment: In my edit, I removed the link to the image, as it was broken, and have uploaded what may be the image you wanted to include. If it is not correct, you can roll it back, or upload a new image.

Comment: Just to be clear, the stamp in the image isn't yours; it is an example of a Schengen-area stamp showing refused entry, but you must have found it on the web somewhere because it is in a US passport and was issued at a Slovenian land border.

Comment: @phoog Correct; I found the link that OP had attempted to include [on this blog](http://thetimetogoisnow.com/2014/09/the-schengen-area-or-how-we-were-stopped-at-the-border-and-denied-entry/)